# Remove subquery in group by query

Tags: sql-server, group-by, subquery

I have the following query. It works as expected. But it has a subquery. Is there a way to optimize it?

```
SELECT Foo,
       count(*)
FROM
  (SELECT Foo
   FROM MyTable
   GROUP BY Foo,
            Bar,
            Baz) AS Subquery
GROUP BY Foo
```

**For the sake of context**

The data set it's working on is as follows:

```
| Foo | Bar | Baz |
|-----|-----|-----|
| a   | 1   |     |
| a   |     | 2   |
| b   | 3   |     |
| b   | 3   |     |
```

The expected result is:

```
| Foo | Count |
|-----|-------|
| a   | 2     |
| b   | 1     |
```

Explained in words. Or trying to.

I want to get the number of distinct Bar and Baz per Foo.

Comment: What is the reason for the subquery at all?

Comment: I don't see how your query could return those results with that sample data

Comment: you are missing a step or something -- the code makes no sense and the results less so.

Comment: @Lamak Oops. I corrected the data set

Comment: Do you need to optimize it? Have you some problems with query performance?

Comment: @Arvo No performance problems. I just wanted to write a better query as subquires are usually bad

Comment: @Snæbjørn Check https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372483 just for fun. There is chance for collision so I won't say it is 100% sure.

Comment: @lad2025 didn't know about http://data.stackexchange.com/ that's so incredibly useful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to optimize that, you may be able to write it a different way, but it will not be faster. You can rewrite it like this, but you can't rewrite it to avoid a subselect:

```
SELECT Foo,
       count(*)
FROM
  (SELECT distinct Foo, bar, baz
   FROM @t
   ) AS Subquery
GROUP BY Foo
```

Comment: Fair enough. I couldn't find one either. But wanted to be sure :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the edit of the question...

```
SELECT Foo, Count(distinct isnull(foo,'-')+isnull(bar,'-')+isnull(baz,'-'))
FROM MyTable
group by foo
```

This is the same functionality as the sub-query if the spacing character is distinct (that is your data does not include `-`

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372553/for-question-32992867

---

I think you want this:

```
SELECT Foo, count(*)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Foo, Bar, Baz
```

---

You might want this:

```
SELECT Foo, Count(*) OVER (Partition By Foo, Bar, Baz)
FROM MyTable
```

---

If these do not give you the result you want please explain why

Comment: For second you probably should add `DISTINCT` https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372453

Comment: Both of thous quires doesn't give distinct Foo column rows. Looking at the dataset provided in the first post I want it to say `a:2, b:1` yours says `a:1, a:1, b:1`

Comment: @Snæbjørn in both cases where it says `Foo, Bar, Baz` replace that with `Foo`.  It is probably the case you get an error making this change if you are using the first case **so** use the windowing function in the second case.

Comment: @hogan both of your examples will give a different result than the query in the question.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk -- maybe, I can't say because the OP keeps changing the question

Comment: This is the result of your query https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372529 and this is the correct result from the query in the question https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372530 they're different.

Comment: That would work. But it's making assumptions about the data and it's not very readable. It's a bit like @lad2025 s suggestion. It works. But not very practical :)

Comment: @Snæbjørn - not .like his at all, his is slow.

Comment: @lad2025 - those two should be distinct values AFAICT from the test data.

Comment: @Hogan Probably yes, I am updating my answer

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:**

This is pure for fun solution, it is not 100% percent reliable and may fail when collision occurs. I post it only as my attempt to get solution without subquery. It won't be faster so please don't use it in production systems.

I assume that there can be one value in columns `Bar` *xor* `Baz`.

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372488)**

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable(Foo VARCHAR(100), Bar VARCHAR(10), Baz VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO #MyTable(Foo, Bar, Baz)
VALUES ('a', '1', NULL), ('a', NULL ,'2'), ('b', '3', NULL),
       ('a', '2', NULL), ('a', NULL ,'1'), ('b', '3', NULL),
       ('a', NULL, '2'), ('a', NULL ,'1'), ('b', '4', NULL),
       ('a', NULL, '1'), ('a', NULL ,'2'), ('b', '7', NULL);

SELECT Foo, COUNT(DISTINCT  
                  CAST(CHECKSUM(Bar, Baz) AS BIGINT) + 
                  CAST(CHECKSUM(Baz, Bar) AS BIGINT) +
                  CAST(CHECKSUM(REVERSE(Bar),REVERSE(Baz)) AS BIGINT) + 
                  CAST(CHECKSUM(REVERSE(Baz),REVERSE(Bar)) AS BIGINT)) 
FROM #MyTable
GROUP BY Foo;
```

**EDIT:**

If `('a', NULL, 1)` and `('a', 1, NULL)` should be distinct you need to use:

**[LiveDemo2](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372666)**

```
SELECT Foo, COUNT(DISTINCT  
                  CAST(CHECKSUM(Bar, Baz) AS BIGINT) + 
                  CAST(CHECKSUM(REVERSE(Bar),REVERSE(Baz)) AS BIGINT))
FROM #MyTable
GROUP BY Foo
```

Any thoughts how to improve it or why it "sucks" appreciated.